# How to use NSArrayController bound to NSUserDefaultsController with custom class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSArrayController bound to NSUserDefaultsController, and the array stores a custom class of mine, which conforms to NSCoding.

It seems like I need NSArchiver, but I can't quite figure out how to glue it all together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [value transformer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/), which you can specify in the options of the binding. You can use `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData` to serialize the array to keyed archive data, or make your own custom value transformer to convert the objects in the array to property lists of your own design.

Comment: This worked awesomely, I just got tripped up not realising that NSValueTransformer was expecting to deal with an array of objects, as opposed to the object directly.

Comment: The value transformer must deal with whatever object is the value of the property, whether that object is a single object or an array object holding other objects.

Comment: @Hope4You: I'm not sure what problem you're referring to. You should ask a separate question about your error.

Comment: @PeterHosey I've deleted the question.